# error event handled but raise an UncaughtExecption in nodejs when using SSH2

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, uncaught-exception

#### ENV

- Node.js version: 0.10.35
- SSH2 version: 0.5.0 (https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2)
- Running on CentOS 7.0

#### ISSUE

I use SSH2 to connect to a remote host on port 22, it works well, but if the remote host refused the connection, an 'error' event emitted by sshClient, the problem is even though I have handled this event, there is an UncaughtException thrown that crashed the node process;

#### I have make some debug like this:

Step 1

```
// In file node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js (line:295)
err.level = 'client-socket';
console.log(‘sock.on: error', JSON.stringify(err)); // I add this log for debugging
self.emit('error', err);
```

And in my code, I tried like this:

```
var SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;
var sshClient = new SSHClient();
sshClient.on('error', function (error) {
     console.error(’sshClient.on: error', JSON.stringify(error));
     error.message = "this error is handled by callback of sshClient.on('error’): ” + error.message;
});
```

then after running my app, in console it printed:

```
sock.on: error {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","level":"client-socket"}
sshClient.on: error {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","level":"client-socket"}

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: this error is handled by callback of sshClient.on('error’): connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

---

Step 2

Then I commented the line:295 in client.js, so it looks like this:

```
err.level = 'client-socket';
console.log(‘sock.on: error', JSON.stringify(err)); // I add this log for debugging
// self.emit('error', err);
```

After running the app again, in console it only printed this message, and process is not crashed

```
sock.on: error {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","level":"client-socket"}
```

#### I am so confused why the error raised an UncaughtException even though I have handled the error event and need help.

thanks for help!

Comment: You must have another `error` event handler that is throwing, another ssh connection being made in parallel that is without an `error` handler, or something similar. I am not able to reproduce the problem, even with node v0.10.35.

Comment: @mscdex when UncaughtException raised, the error object has a message which is modified by me in error event handler: `sshClient.on('error', function (error) {
     console.error(’sshClient.on: error', JSON.stringify(error));`
     **error.message = "this error is handled by callback of sshClient.on('error’): ” + error.message;**
`});`, Is that means the 'error' is not the another one but the same?